# PHP: Adding a key-value pair to an array

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$array = Array ( [0] => Array ( [site_id] => 89193)
            [1] => Array ( [site_id] => 89093)
            [2] => Array ( [site_id] => 3059 )
         )
```

What I want to do is to add a new pair to the array, how can I do so?

For example, next to `site_id`, I want to add the key `[site_name]` and its value.

Comment: For which of the entries? All of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as &$child) {
    $child['site_name'] = $value;
}
```

or, without references:

```
foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
   $array[$key]['site_name'] = $value;
}
```